# Can ERC tokens change their creation code or parameters afterwards?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-20

Probably a dead stupid question, but just to make sure: can ERC20 or other tokens based on Ethereum Smart Contracts alter their properties after the creation?

For example, can they change decimals value, abi, code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.Contract can't change its byte code once it has been deployed.